# What is the title of the song that plays during the next episode(18) previews of Parasyte -the maxim-?

Tags: music, parasyte

What is the title of the short insert soundtrack that plays at the end of every episode in **Parasyte -the maxim-**? During the next episode(18) previews (see images), a suspenseful/thriller song is being played as background music instead of the usual vague voice-overs. It really rocks and I want to know because I feel as though I have heard it being used in other anime aside from this one.

[image: Parasyte - The Maxim - Episode 12 Prev 1]
[image: Parasyte - The Maxim - Episode 12 Prev 2]

Answer (score 8):

Though this one sounds like a dubstep version, I think it's [Hypnotik](https://soundcloud.com/parasyte-the-maxim-ost/hypnotik).

Comment: @GaoWeiwei Ah, great find. That does indeed sound very similar to the next episode preview.